# Android Studio:: Dependency issues

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

I have added in gradle dependency and get

```
"Error: Program type already present: io.realm.BaseRealm$5"
```

during compilation of the project.

```
    implementation 'com.isseiaoki:simplecropview:1.1.7'
```

this is the new dependency which is the cause of this error with realm dependency

Comment: can you ad your project and app gradle ?

Comment: try `implementation('com.isseiaoki:simplecropview:1.1.7') {
        exclude group: "io.realm.BaseRealm"
    }`

Comment: I have tried but it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

run following command to see the list of dependencies and check for 'com.isseiaoki:simplecropview' and share that data along with app/build.gradle

```
gradlew dependencies
```